# Access active palette colors in MudBlazor

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I have a .NET 7 Blazor Webassembly app that uses MudBlazor (newest version) and has light and dark mode:

Extract from `MainLayout.razor`:

```
<MudThemeProvider Theme="_myTheme" IsDarkMode="_preferences.IsDarkMode"/>
```

I have a bunch of my own components that currently have their own colors set based on some logic (eg. if a number is positive or negative).

How do I access the current **active palette colors** in my own components so that they also change to dark colors, when switching from the light to the dark palette?

I haven't been able to find any documentation relating to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use the MudBlazor Color enumeration, but will also need to use a MudBlazor component to resolve that to the appropriate theme color.

For example:

```
<h1 style:"color: @(MudBlazor.Color.Info)">Show me Info Color</h1>
```

will not work.

This is because MudBlazor.Color.Info does not resolve to an html color definition on its own.  It resolves to an enumerator value that the Mud Component will then use to create a class name that the MudBlazor css files will then resolve to the html color.

So, to get the required effect you'd need to use the following:

```
<MudText Typo=@Typo.h1 Color=@Color.Info>Show me Info Color</MudText>
```

This will then use the Info color from the active Mud theme's palette.

In summary, you'd need to use MudText component in your own components to leverage MudBlazor theming.

Alternatively, you could copy the internals of the MudBlazor component by adding the following string to your class:

```
$"mud-{MudBlazor.Color.Info.ToDescriptionString()}-text"
```

but much easier just to use the MudText component.

For reference, here's the source of how a MudText converts the Color parameter to an appropriate class name:

```
public partial class MudText : MudComponentBase
{
    protected string Classname =>
    new CssBuilder("mud-typography")
      .AddClass($"mud-typography-{Typo.ToDescriptionString()}")
      .AddClass($"mud-{Color.ToDescriptionString()}-text", Color != Color.Default && Color != Color.Inherit)
      .AddClass("mud-typography-gutterbottom", GutterBottom)
      .AddClass($"mud-typography-align-{ConvertAlign(Align).ToDescriptionString()}", Align != Align.Inherit)
      .AddClass("mud-typography-display-inline", Inline)
      .AddClass(Class)
    .Build();
```